# Web-scraping from Coinbase with Python (Pycharm)

Tags: python, web-scraping, bitcoin, coinbase-api

I am trying to write some code that will give me the price in BTC when I run it. Although I am **not** getting an error after running the code, I am not getting the price and I am getting **NONE**. Can anyone look at my code and figure out what the problem is? Here is the code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.coinbase.com/charts")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
seven_day = soup.find(id="seven-day-forecast")
bitcoin = soup.find('pre',{'style':'word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-
wrap;'})

print(bitcoin)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe because `document.getElementById("seven-day-forecast") = null`

Answer (score 1):

Data that you want to scrape is dinamycally generated. You can make direct request to API to get those values:

```
url = 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/USD/spot?'
response = requests.get(url).json()
print(response)
```

*Output:*

```
{'data': [{'currency': 'USD', 'base': 'BTC', 'amount': '7590.01'}, {'currency':
'USD', 'base': 'ETH', 'amount': '296.86'}, {'currency': 'USD', 'base': 'LTC', 'amount': '54.59'}]}
```

To get required value:

```
print(response['data'][0]['amount'])
```

*Output:*

```
'7590.01'
```

Comment: @Jay , any feedback?