# Why is Beautiful soup not finding the html element I am looking for?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get cryptocurrency price changes from coinbase by parsing with beautiful soup. on the coinbase website (https://www.coinbase.com/price/ethereum) I can find the html element for the price change.

```
<h4 class="TextElement__Spacer-hxkcw5-0 caIgfs Header__StyledHeader-sc-1xiyexz-0 dLILyj">+0.33%</h4>
```

And then in python I use beautiful soup to find this element by looking through the h4 tag and it finds other h4 tags but not the one i am looking for

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

 result = requests.get("https://www.coinbase.com/price/ethereum")
 src = result.content
 soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "html.parser")
 tags = soup.find_all("h4")
 print (tags)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web-scraping from Coinbase with Python (Pycharm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122418/web-scraping-from-coinbase-with-python-pycharm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is embedded in the page inside `<script>` tag. You can use `json` module to parse it.

For example:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.coinbase.com/price/ethereum'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

data = json.loads(soup.select_one('script#server-app-state').contents[0])

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print( data['initialData']['data']['prices']['prices']['latestPrice']['percentChange'] )
```

Prints:

```
{'hour': 0.0038781959207123133, 'day': -0.0025064363163135772, 'week': -0.02360650279511788, 'month': 0.13293312491891887, 'year': -0.10963199613423964}
```

---

EDIT:

The line `data = json.loads(soup.select_one('script#server-app-state').contents[0])` will:

1.) select element `<script id="server-app-state">...</script>` from the soup

2.) the contents of this tag is Json string, so I decode it with [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html#json.loads)

3.) the result is stored to variable `data` (a python dictionary)

The line `print( data['initialData']['data']['prices']['prices']['latestPrice']['percentChange'] )` will just print a content from this dictionary (you can see complete content of this dictionary by uncommenting the line `print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))`